# Laravel Eloquent Inner join where multiple data from another table return in property as an array

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, inner-join, eloquent-relationship

Suppose, I have two tables; tableA and tableB. For tableA single row's id there are multiple rows in tableB.

[image: tableA]

[image: tableB]

Now I want all tableA data including tableB, that's matches by id (tableA->id === tableB->blood_request_id)

The return will be

```
[
 ...tableA data,
 'blood_request_id' => [1, 2]
]
```

Comment: sounds like a ```hasMany``` and ```belongsTo``` basic relationship, did you check https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships ?